# Jenkins - Login only externally?

Tags: security, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to set-up Jenkins security in a way that, when accessed from the internal network the user will be assigned Admin privileges, and when accessed from the outside it would require a log-in?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, because Jenkins does not expose client (web browser) information to scripts, so you don't know what network they come from.